# Determine the value of a for which the system has no solution, exactly one solution, or infinitely many solutions. (Variation 2)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a student taking Linear Algebra and I have attempted to solve this question and I'm wondering whether my conclusion is right, I did not get a conclusion for if the solution can have one exact solution so if i did miss anything, it'd be nice if someone can point that out!

I used elementary-row operations on the system as a matrix, and tried turning it into a row reduced echelon form. If there is an easier way, I'd also welcome it.

---

Text Format:

**System Of Linear Equations**
Determine the values of a for which the system has no solution, exactly one solution or infinitely many solutions.

```
x + 2y - 3z = 4
3x - y + 5z = 2
4x + y + 2z = a + 2
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you made a couple of mistakes in your working, and the reduced row echelon form of the left-hand matrix is actually the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.

With that said, if you have an $n \times n$ reduced row echelon form with a bottom row that is all zeros to the left of the bar then you either have infinitely many solutions or none. Having exactly one solution is only possible if your RREF is the identity matrix.

Comment: oh thanks, i did not notice, i will keep that in my head.

Comment: i have ran this same matrix through wolfram alpha, and it did not turn out to be a 3x3 identity matrix?

Comment: I notice that the equation you typed in the post don't match the matrix you wrote in your notes - there's a sign mismatch in the 3rd equation. I agree that if the correct matrix is the one in the image then it has one zero row, although I think you still made some algebraic errors by the look of it.

Comment: yeah the equation in the system was 4x + y + 2z = a+2, my bad